# Replacing datetime conditionally - python

Tags: python, pandas, date, numpy, datetime

I have a 'Posting Date' column in the dataframe in the format of `'2017-03-01'`. The type is `<datetime64>[ns]`. And I want to change the value if it is after '2017-03-31' to '2017-03-31', and all others remain unchanged.

When I type `df['Posting Date']>'2017-03-31'`,it can correctly show me all the rows where the condition is met. So I guess the date filtering function works.

However, when I used `numpy.where` to write the condition as this:

```
df['Posting Date'] = np.where(df['Posting Date']>'2017-03-31','2017-03-31,'df['Posting Date'])
```

it incurrs an `invalid type promotion` error.

I also tried `df.loc` and the same error occers.

```
df.loc[df['Posting Date']>'2017-03-31','Posting Date']='2017-03-31'
```

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-03-31'`

I'm wondering why the error occurs. How can I replace date correctly? Whatever method which works is fine.

Comment: I think you've got a cut-and-paste error.  `'2017-03-31,'df['Posting Date']` is a syntax error.  (Presumably the comma should be _outside_ the quotes.)  If this is actually correct numpy syntax, my apologies.

Comment: I haven’t tried it but you can try. df[‘Posting Date’].clip(upper=pd.Timestamp(‘2017-03-31’))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of are trying to replace datetime with string in datetime dtype column so pass a datetime in np.where i.e

```
df['Posting Date'] = np.where(df['Posting Date']>'2017-03-31',pd.to_datetime(['2017-03-31']),df['Posting Date'])
```

Example output :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Posting Date': pd.to_datetime(['20-4-2017','20-4-2017','20-4-2017','20-3-2017','20-2-2017'])})
df['Posting Date'] = np.where(df['Posting Date']>'2017-03-31',pd.to_datetime(['2017-03-31']),df['Posting Date'])
```

Output :

```
Posting Date
0   2017-03-31
1   2017-03-31
2   2017-03-31
3   2017-03-20
4   2017-02-20
```

Better one posted by [@pirSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751078/replacing-datetime-conditionally-python/46752094#comment80448204_46751078) in comment using clip i.e

```
df['Posting Date'] = df['Posting Date'].clip(upper=pd.Timestamp('2017-03-31'))
```

Comment: Glad to help @LavenderPan

Comment: For someone that might land here having the same problem as I did. Was doing the where almost like what Dark said but all values that were not supposed to be replaced were being set as integer numbers instead of Datetime as they were before. What I have missed was the [ ] nesting the string date inside the pd.to_datetime(). The why I don't know.